# FB Like button won't show

Tags: javascript, html, css, facebook

I have no Java experience, I've purely followed the FB 'walkthrough' but had no luck. Basically I'm looking to add this button, a little under the welcoming image and align right. Helpful if I could see the darn thing...

```css
    .container {
      padding-top: 0px;
      padding-left: 0px;
      padding-right: 10px;
      font-family: arial;
      z-index: 2;
    }
    a {
      float: right;
      text-decoration: none;
      padding-left: 10px;
      color: #003399;
    }
    li {
      display: inline;
    }
    .navbar {
      float: right;
      padding-top: 75px;
      padding-bottom: 45px;
      padding-right: 0px;
      z-index: 2;
    }
    #intro img {
      position: absolute;
      display: block;
      margin: auto;
      max-width: 100%;
      height: auto;
      z-index: 1;
    }
    .fb-like {
      position: absolute;
      display: block;
      z-index: 3;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
  <title>St George's League - Home</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="fb-root"></div>
  <script language="JavaScript">
    (function(d, s, id) {
      var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
      if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
      js = d.createElement(s);
      js.id = id;
      js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.0";
      fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
  </script>
  <div style="min-width: 800px; min-height: 600px; margin: 0 auto">
    <div class="container">
      <ul>
        <div class="nav">
          <li>
            <img src="images/sgl-logo.jpg" height="145px" alt="SGLLogo" />
          </li>

          <div class="navbar">
            <li class="contact"><a href="contact.html">CONTACT</a>
            </li>
            <li class="about"><a href="about.html">ABOUT</a>
              <li class="leagues"><a href="leagues.html">LEAGUES</a>
              </li>
              <strong><li class="home"><a href="index.html">HOME</a></li></strong> 
          </div>
          <!--Nav End-->
        </div>
        <!--Navbar End-->
    </div>
    <!--Container End-->
    <div id="intro">
      <img src="images/intro.jpg" />
    </div>
    <!--Intro End-->
  </div>
  <!--Style End-->
  <div class="fb-like" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/StGeorgesLeagues" data-width="80" data-layout="button_count" data-action="like" data-show-faces="false" data-share="true">
  </div>
  <!--FB Like End-->

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't find anything wrong with the initial script or the call to it to display the button. With Facebook you can have a personal page and you can also be an admin on other pages as well. Where this is embedded at your site the button will not display unless you are logged into Facebook. If not logged into Facebook you'll get a small clickable link that says login. Once you then login to Facebook that login link will disappear and the like button will pop up. Just to be thorough I pasted your code into my website and your like button displayed just fine...